# Can astronauts of a certain rank perform marriages on board of a spacecraft?

Tags: law

Sea captains can [perform marriages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sea_captain#Performing_marriages) under the law of certain countries and in specified conditions. But what about space captains (or a similar rank)?

Has an issue of marriage in space, in orbit or on another cosmic body ever been discussed in the history of spaceflight? I imagine it must have been, with how people like to do weddings in special ways and in special places.

Comment: related: [Is it possible to get married in space?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/24819/12102)